# Convert C++ template parameter to string in a structure

Tags: c++, templates

I need to convert a template value to a string. I have the following C++ structure (I'm using qt) :

```
template <class T>
struct MyStruct
{
    QString name;
    T value;

    QString get_value() {
        if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) return QString::number(value);
        if (std::is_same<T, double>::value) return QString::number(value,'f',8);
        if (std::is_same<T, QString>::value) return value;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile. I found the explanation here : [How do I cast a C++ template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291704/how-do-i-cast-a-c-template-parameter)

I understand the problem and why it doesn't compile, but I can't find a solution. Is there a way to do this ?

**Update :**

I'm using c++11 so I can't use `if constexpr`.Finally, I got it to work with `std::enable_if` :

```
template <class T>
struct MyStruct
{
    QString name;
    T value;

    template<typename Q = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, double>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    QString value_to_string() {
        return QString::number(value,'f',8);
    }

    template<typename Q = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, int>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    QString value_to_string() {
        return QString::number(value);
    }

    template<typename Q = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, QString>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    QString value_to_string() {
        return value;
    }

};
```

thanks

Comment: `if constexpr` like in the second answer from your link?

Comment: Perhaps `std::enable_if` can help. Try making as many functions (each with `std::enable_if`) as conversions you want to make. Not sure that it will work though. (Edit: it does work, as explained in the answer linked atop this post).